# Convert column to date when date in format dd.mm.yyyy

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df where date is in format dd.mm.yyyy. I want to convert this column into date datatype.

df

```
Date        Col1   Col2
23.11.2020  V1     100
22.10.1990  V2     200
31.12.1890  V4     79
```

How to convert date column to date type. Right now `Date` column is object type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd
d = {"Date": ["23.11.2020", "22.10.1990", "31.12.1890"], "Col1": ["V1", "V2", "V4"], "Col2": [100, 200, 79]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"], format='%d.%m.%Y', errors='coerce').dt.date
df

    Date    Col1    Col2
0   2020-11-23  V1  100
1   1990-10-22  V2  200
2   1890-12-31  V4  79

df.dtypes

Date    object
Col1    object
Col2     int64
dtype: object
```

Comment: How to get only date, no datetime

Comment: @noob What resulting type you want? I have added extra info about types.

Comment: I want to return only dates , i dont want datetime. Only the date part should come not the time stamp

Comment: Ok, to get `datetime.date` you can use `.dt.date` with `to_datetime`. I've updated an answer.

Comment: @m0nhawk - The format applied to the `Date` column isn't preserved. The original is `dd-mm-yy`. While here it becomes `yy-mm-dd`.

Answer (score 3):

Does this solve your question?

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Any other queries on this question are welcome!
Happy Coding!

Comment: Since OP wants only `date` part, you can do this: `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d.%m.%Y').dt.date`.